# ConstraintLayout Barrier not respecting Group

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

I have a Barrier which references **three views**. These three views are beneath one another, like this:

```
---- View A

---- View B

---- Group 

--------- Barrier

---- View D
```

**View D** has a constraint to the Barrier and View B and the Group at any time may become become `View.GONE`.

Furthermore, the **Group** is initially empty. I programmatically inflate views under View B and I associate all of them to the Group.

The **Problem** though is that when I inflate views in to the Group, **View D** does not move and stays underneath View B.

Code which shows the Group, the Barrier and View D:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_b" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/header_barrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="group, view_a, view_b" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom_shadow"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_8"
    android:background="@drawable/orders_shadow_white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Please add whole code and share what exact layout you want

Answer (score 1):

> You have made mistake in ***bottom_shadow*** View's constarint.

It should be ***layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf***    instead of  ***layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf***.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/view_a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_a" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view_b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_b" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/header_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="group, view_a, view_b" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_shadow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header_barrier" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```